# How to iterate over a dataframe that's processed in another function?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, iterator, iteration

I want to use the `reactome2py` package to analyse pathways by adapting the `Reference code`.

I want to iterate over the dataframe (e.g., df for `data_linear_cna.txt`).

Reference code:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1OufIYapCWirfLsudpg0fw1OxD7KTud2y?usp=sharing#scrollTo=e1q6oxLUKGGR

The portion of the code that's throwing the error:

```
cna = DataProcessing(directory + "data_linear_cna.txt")
cna_result = [analysis.identifiers(ids=",".join(d)) for d in cna]
```

"Full" code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from reactome2py import analysis, content, utils


def get_pathways(t):

    # Exclude disease pathways
    token_result = analysis.token(token=t, species="Homo sapiens", page_size="-1", page="-1", sort_by="ENTITIES_FDR", order="ASC", resource="TOTAL", p_value="1", include_disease=False, min_entities=None, max_entities=None)
    l = [p["name"] for p in token_result["pathways"]]
    l.sort()
    return l


class DataProcessing:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.df = pd.read_csv(data, sep="\t").drop("Entrez_Gene_Id", axis=1, errors="ignore")
        self.df = self.df.loc[:, ~self.df.columns.duplicated()]
        self.df = self.df.sort_index()



def main():

    cna = DataProcessing(directory + "data_linear_cna.txt")

    cna_result = [analysis.identifiers(ids=",".join(d)) for d in cna]
    cna_tokens = [r["summary"]["token"] for r in cna_result]
main()
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "data_gen_files/main.py", line 336, in <module>
    main()
  File "data_gen_files/main.py", line 133, in main
    cna_result = [analysis.identifiers(ids=",".join(d)) for d in cna]
TypeError: 'DataProcessing' object is not iterable
```

Example dataframe:

```
pd.DataFrame([[MEOX2, 0.041451, 0.103890, 0.060789, 0.025519, 0.041260],[COX8C, 0.981055, 0.989163,0.979539, 0.985666, 0.982094],[IMPA2, 0.018580, 0.127843, 0.019699, 0.018484, 0.019477],[TTC8, 0.037853, 0.061488, 0.061730, 0.084045, 0.056650],[TMEM186, 0.858835, 0.718749, 0.887326, 0.862945, 0.909910]], columns = ['Hugo_Symbol', 'Entrez_Gene_Id'], 'TCGA-02-0001-01'], 'TCGA-02-0003-01'], 'TCGA-02-0006-01'], 'TCGA-02-0007-01'], 'TCGA-02-0009-01'])
```

Comment: `cna` is not even a function, but an object. Either a `DataProcessing` instance, or a dataframe; that is unclear, because you show `cna = DataProcessing(directory + "data_linear_cna.txt")` as well as `cna = pd.DataFrame([[MEOX2, 0.041451, ...]], columns = ['Hugo_Symbol', 'Entrez_Gene_Id'], , ...])`. Both are not iterable, but one is not like the other.

Comment: Why do you think you can iterate over an instance of DataProcessing? What is a single item, e.g. `d` in your list comprehension, supposed to be?

Comment: [https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/basics.html#iteration](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/basics.html#iteration)

Comment: I think you wanted to iterate through cna.df:
cna_result = [analysis.identifiers(ids=",".join(d)) for d in cna.df]